# Pegar as informações do formulário e envia-las para e-mail

Tags: javascript, jquery

Possuo um formulário que terei que pegar as informações digitadas e enviar para o meu e-mail via java script ou jquery porem não sei como fazer isso até o momento somente validei o meu formulário segue o código do meu formulário:

```css
.corpo-1 ul li {

  display: block;

  margin: 10px;

  text-align: center;

}

.corpo-1 ul {

  margin-top: 10%;

}

.contato-barra {

  width: 10%;

  height: 2px;

  background-color: #000;

  border: none;

}

input[type="text"] {

  border: 1px solid #000;

  border-radius: 5px;

  width: 300px;

  height: 25px;

  background-color: transparent;

  font-family: Gabriola;

  font-size: 1.2em;

  outline: none;

}

.teste1 {

  margin-left: 65%;

  background-color: aquamarine;

  width: 100px;

  height: 50px;

  color: #000;

  display: none;

}

select {

  border: 1px solid #000;

  border-radius: 5px;

  width: 300px;

  height: 40px;

  background-color: transparent;

  font-family: Gabriola;

  font-size: 1.2em;

  outline: none;

}

textarea {

  border: 1px solid #000;

  border-radius: 5px;

  width: 300px;

  height: 100px;

  background-color: transparent;

  font-family: Gabriola;

  font-size: 1.2em;

  outline: none;

}

#enviar {

  background-color: #000;

  width: 300px;

  height: 50px;

  border: none;

  border-radius: 5px;

  color: #fff;

  font-family: Gabriola;

  font-size: 1.3em;

  text-align: center;

  cursor: pointer;

  outline: none;

}

#enviar:hover {

  background-color: #333;

}

#bg-fundo {

  position: absolute;

  z-index: -1;

  opacity: 0.25;

  left: 0;

  right: 0;

  margin: auto;

  margin-top: -18%;

  /*width: 50%;*/

  transform: scale(1);

}
```

```html
<section class="corpo-1">
  <div id="formulario">
    <form method="post" action="">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="text" id="nome" placeholder="  Digite seu nome" required name=nome>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="text" placeholder="  Digite seu Email" required name=email>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="text" placeholder="  Digite seu Nickname" required name=nickname>
        </li>
        <li>
          <select>
            <option value="the-elder" selected>--- Selecione um jogo ---</option>
            <option value="the-elder">The Elder Scrols Online</option>
            <option value="archage">ArcheAge</option>
            <option value="worlofwarcraft">World of War Craft</option>
            <option value="forsaken">Forsaken World</option>
            <option value="leagueoflegends">League of Legends</option>
            <option value="dota">Dota 2</option>
            <option value="smite">Smite</option>
            <option value="warface">Warface</option>
            <option value="cs">CS-GO</option>
            <option value="bf">Battle Field</option>
            <option value="cod">Call of Dutty</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>
          <textarea placeholder="  Mensagem" required name=mensagem></textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type=submit value="Enviar" id="enviar" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Obs: O meu email sera enviado para o meu no caso felipe-webdesigner@hotmail.com

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível enviar email usando somente JavaScript. Você deverá usar uma linguagem de servidor para isso, por exemplo PHP.

Mas você pode usar o comando `window.open('mailto:teste@exemplo.com');` para abrir o programa de email padrão e enviar o email.

Você pode também passar parâmetros no comando: `window.open('mailto:teste@exemplo.com?subject=assunto&body=corpo');`

**Exemplo em PHP:**

```
<?php
$para       = 'alguem@exemplo.com';
$assunto    = 'Algum Assunto';
$mensagem   = 'Olá';
$cabecalhos = 'From: seuemail@exemplo.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: seuemail@exemplo.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($para, $assunto, $mensagem, $cabecalhos);
?>
```

Comment: existe alguma documentação disso ou algum lugar com o codigo pronto ou com mais informaçoes eu nao manjo dessas coisas

Comment: @Kirito http://lmgtfy.com/?q=mailto

Comment: @Kirito Sobre como mandar email com PHP podes ver o manual oficial: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php

Comment: amigosei que nao e da sua conta mais sou muito ruim com essas linguagem seria possivel posar um prototipo de  codigo para eu poder entender melhor se nao for pedir muito

Comment: @Kirito Atualizei a resposta com um exemplo em PHP.

Comment: @Earendul amigo entao omeu arquivo contato esta com a extensão .html eu terei que mudala tbm e colocar .php??? e quanto a seu codigo eu coloco ele no corpo do meu site ou no head do meu arquivo

Comment: @Earendul   amigo abri um novo topico com meu codigo php da uma olhada la :  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66243/formul%C3%A1rio-n%C3%A3o-envia-as-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-o-e-mail

Answer (score 1):

Realmente tem que usar uma linguagem no servidor para enviar seu e-mail. O PHP é muito bom nisso, [leia aqui](http://wiki.locaweb.com/pt-br/Como_enviar_e-mails_com_a_fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_mail%28%29_do_PHP) um artigo bem completo sobre como fazer isso.

Existe também o PHPMailer, [aqui existe outro artigo](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/enviar-e-mails-pelo-php-usando-o-phpmailer/) explicando sobre ele.