# Formulário não envia as informações para o e-mail

Tags: php, html5

Preciso que as informações do meu formulário sejam enviadas para o meu e-mail eu estou fazendo em *php* porem não funciona segue meu código:

```
        <form action="email.php" method="post">
    <label for="Nome">nome:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Nome" size="35" /><br>

    <label for="Email">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Email" size="35" /><br>

    <label for="Fone">Telefone:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Fone" size="35" /><br>

    <label for="Mensagem">Mensagem:</label>
    <textarea name="Mensagem" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea><br> 

    <input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

meu código em *php* esta em um arquivo separado do meu código:

```
    <?php
$Nome       = $_POST["Nome"];   // Pega o valor do campo Nome
$Fone       = $_POST["Fone"];   // Pega o valor do campo Telefone
$Email      = $_POST["Email"];  // Pega o valor do campo Email
$Mensagem   = $_POST["Mensagem"];   // Pega os valores do campo Mensagem

// Variável que junta os valores acima e monta o corpo do email

$Vai        = "Nome: $Nome\n\nE-mail: $Email\n\nTelefone: $Fone\n\nMensagem: $Mensagem\n";

require_once("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

define('GUSER', 'felipe.henrique1446@gmail.com');   // <-- Insira aqui o seu GMail
define('GPWD', 'lalala123');        // <-- Insira aqui a senha do seu GMail

function smtpmailer($para, $de, $de_nome, $assunto, $corpo) { 
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();        // Ativar SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;       // Debugar: 1 = erros e mensagens, 2 = mensagens apenas
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // Autenticação ativada
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';  // SSL REQUERIDO pelo GMail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // SMTP utilizado
    $mail->Port = 587;          // A porta 587 deverá estar aberta em seu servidor
    $mail->Username = GUSER;
    $mail->Password = GPWD;
    $mail->SetFrom($de, $de_nome);
    $mail->Subject = $assunto;
    $mail->Body = $corpo;
    $mail->AddAddress($para);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Mensagem enviada!';
        return true;
    }
}

// Insira abaixo o email que irá receber a mensagem, o email que irá enviar (o mesmo da variável GUSER), 

 if (smtpmailer('felipe.henrique1446@gmail.com', 'felipe.henrique1446@gmail.com', 'felipe', 'Assunto do Email', $Vai)) {

    Header("location:http://www.dominio.com.br/obrigado.html"); // Redireciona para uma página de obrigado.

}
if (!empty($error)) echo $error;
?>
```

executo o projeto e deu esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ao invés de usar somente `\n`, use `\r\n` como quebra de linha.

Comment: @qmechanik amigo entao nao aconteceu nada eu lico no botao de enciar e ele me redireciona para uma pagina onde tem oi meu codigo php na tela e nao envia

Comment: Voce ta com a aplicação em ambiente local?

Comment: ss local eu nem hospedei meu site ainda e sou muito novato em php começei hoje digamos asim rsrsrsrs

Comment: Quando você envia o formulário, ele vai pra página .php que contém o código e exibe ele? Então o problema está no seu servidor web. Verifique se instalou corretamente o PHP e o Apache.

Comment: Dá uma olhada neste tópico: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532486/failed-to-connect-to-mailserver-at-localhost-port-25   **OBS:** Não é mais fácil você utilizar PHPMailer ou SwiftMailer?

Comment: Coloque seu `$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;` com o valor 2. `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` e veja o que aconteceu.

Comment: amigo deu um erro diferente vou editar o post e colocar o erro que deu

Comment: Dá uma olhada na tabela de configuração do gmail: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=pt-BR de acordo com essa documentação a porta 587 usa TLS, tente mudar para a porta 465. (Espero que seja isso mesmo...) ou altere seu `SMTPSecure` para `tls`

Comment: Oi,
vá em: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps e maque a opção: `Ativar`.
De um tempo até você receber um email do Google dizendo que a segurança foi desabilitada e tente rodar o script.
Após isso modifique: `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';`  `$mail->Port = 465;`

Comment: pronto vou esperar agora e ver no que da demora muto ???  para receber a mensagem

Comment: obrigadooooo rapaziadaaaa amo vcsssssssssssss uhuuuuuu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $headers .= "From:  dominio.com.br<sistema@dominio.com.br>\n";
  $headers .= "X-Sender:  <sistema@dominio.com.br>\n";
  $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP  v".phpversion()."\n";
  $headers .= "X-IP:  ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n";
  $headers .= "Return-Path:  <sistema@dominio.com.br>\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
```

Você precisa configurar esse trecho com informações do seu servidor ou de um servidor de terceiros, por isso não esta funcionando.

Já que você está aprendendo, esse [artigo](http://www.gn10.com.br/blog/dicas/envie-emails-php-smtp-gmail-google-apps/) pode te ajudar na configuração de envio de e-mails via SMTP pelo Gmail que é gratuito.

Comment: ola amigo coloquei no wamp server e deu esse erro ai acima eu editei e coloquei um print no post

Comment: cara e que comecei meio que hoje com o php nao manjo nada eu preciso alterar tipo oque por exemplo

Answer (score 1):

O código PHP precisa ser compilado, e para isso você precisa de um servidor WEB (HTTP) e o PHP para executar o código!

Instale o WAMP ou o XAMPP ou o EasyPHP

[WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

[XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/index.html)

[EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/)

Esses pacotes WAMP (Windows, Apache, MySQL, PHP) (ou LAMP - onde o L é de Linux)
são programa que instalam o servidor Web (Apache), o PHP e um banco de dados (MySQL) e ai você consegue testar o seu código PHP na sua máquina.

Assim que você instalar e iniciar o Apache (servidor web), você irá colocar os arquivos em uma pasta pré determinada (Depende de onde você instalou o servidor) e ai poderá acessar por http://localhost/nomeDoSeuArquivo.php e fazer os testes!

**Envio de e-mail via SMTP**

Para enviar os e-mails, você precisará de um servidor [SMTP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol), porém não recomendo que tente instalar um em sua máquina, porque além de dor de cabeça, se não for muito bem configurado, alguém pela internet pode acabar enviando SPAM pelo seu computador para qualquer lugar do mundo.

Caso deseje testar o envio de e-mails, recomendo que instale o [Papercut](https://github.com/changemakerstudios/papercut). Ele é um pequeno servidor SMTP que envia qualquer e-mail para ele mesmo. Assim você consegue testar e visualizar o e-mail diretamente por ele. Basta baixa-lo e instalar, depois só tentar enviar o e-mail novamente pelo PHP e irá ver que o Papercut recebeu uma nova mensagem!

Comment: ola amigo coloquei no wamp server e deu esse erro ai acima eu editei e coloquei um print no post

Comment: Boa, isso significa que está funcionado! O que acontece é que para enviar e-mails você precisa de um servidor [SMTP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) e como você não tem um em sua máquina (nem perca tempo tentando instalar um, caso a máquina seja apenas de testes), recomendo que ou ignore o erro, ou caso queira mesmo ver como o e-mail irá chegar, utilize um servidor SMTP de testes, como o [PaperCut](https://papercut.codeplex.com/)